# Does common X-like picture represent one doubled chromosome or two homologous chromosomes?

Tags: cell-biology, chromosome

What is on common X-like picture of chromosome?

Here is the [image from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatid):

[image]

Are (for example) lower petals homologous to each other?

If yes, then why `(1)` is entitled as *chromatid: one-half of two identical threadlike strands of a replicated chromosome*? Homologous parts are similar but not identical.

If no, then why does human chromosomes are often denoted by Xs:

[image]

Do we have 23 Xs (females) or 46 Xs?

Comment: You should the wikipedia legends on the post

Comment: I have cited important one.

Comment: Sure, but if you give more info and thoughts, it might be easier for us to understand what is unclear to you. This seems particularly important as I don't understand your comments below my answer.

Comment: @Remi.b note that I am absolutely agree with your answer and this is my "zero hypothesis". But I am confused, that sometimes X-like patterns are apparently used to depict homologous chromosomes.

Comment: Ok. If the legend under the figure (wherever you found it) says that it displays homologous chromosomes, then the legend is wrong! A single X-like shape always represents a single chromosome.

Comment: Please indicate the source of your second image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "X" you see is a *chromosome*. The two strands that forms the X-shaped chromosome are called *chromatids*. As they are bound together (by the centromer), they are called *sister chromatids*. Note that chromosomes look like that only during the metaphase. Note also, that not all chromosomes have a centromer that is in the middle of the chromosome as it is obvious from the picture in your question.

Many species (including humans) have two sets of each chromosome. If you add the other chromosome in the picture, you would see a pair of chromosome. One chromosome of the pair is said to be *homologous* to the other one. Below is a cladogram during the metaphase of a human (I let you figure out the sex) showing each pair of chromosome.

[image]

Sister chromatids are identical (except for mutation during the last chromosomal replication). Homologous chromosomes are similar but not identical. Crossover occurs in between chromatids of homologous chromosomes.

**Further comment on your figure**

There are 23 pairs of chromosomes, that is 46 chromosomes. Your picture shows only one chromosome per pair, that is your picture shows only 23 chromosomes. In other words, your picture shows the haploid genome and not the diploid genome.

Comment: See the picture of human genome. It is depicted as 23 Xs (some not fully formed).

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Can you develop? Do you think I answered your question?

Comment: So, pictures, depicting 23-24 X-like feutures are just incorrect?

Comment: See my update. I have added a picture. These pictures are common. Search human genome in google images.

Comment: Sure, I see the picture. I don't understand what you think would be incorrect on this picture based on my answer. Can you please develop further what is unclear? Note that your picture only show a single chromosome (two chromatids) of each of the 23 pairs.

Comment: Regard object #1 on my picture. There are ~ 23 of such objects in my picture. Hence, this object is representing 1/23 of genome. Hence, it represents 2 chromosomes. Probably, homologous ones. This object is depicted as X. Hence, strands are homologous, not identical. But you said strands are identical (not regarding mutations).

Comment: Please see edit "further comment on your figure"  and let me know if it helps.

Comment: To whoever is concerned: Please leave a comment when downvoting. Such downvotes are really not helpful at improving the answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote

Comment: I never thought you did. No worries!